# Plivo how to get call status?

Tags: javascript, node.js, plivo

Im trying to get the status of an outgoing call, but I'm just getting in-progress status and i'm stuck in that how can i get the others aswell, like ringing, completed, failed etc??

```
            app.get('/make_call/', (req, res) => { 
            var r = plivo.Response();

            let call_uuid = req.param('CallUUID')
            let status = req.param('CallStatus')

            console.log("Call UUID:", call_uuid)
            console.log("Call Status:", status)
            

            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});
            res.end(r.toXML());

        })
```

OUTPUT:

```
Call UUID: f6dcc5f3-aaf7-4ffa-b2b4-0fa3f643017a
Call Status: in-progress
```

Answer (score 0):

My name is Mohammed Huzaif, and I work at Plivo as a Product Evangelist. The call status is sent to the callback and action URL you specified in your `<Dial XML>`.

You can find a detailed description of the implementation in this [document](https://www.plivo.com/docs/voice/use-cases/dial-status-reporting/node/#xml-how-it-works). If you require any additional assistance, please do not hesitate to contact our [support team](https://support.plivo.com/hc/en-us).